# Game show buzzer screens

Tags: html, button

I'm doing a training class right now and one of the games I plan on doing is a Jeopardy style of Q & A. The problem I'm trying to figure out is the buzzer. My idea is to use the projector as the question board I control. The trainees would go to an HTML page with nothing more than a single button. They would turn their monitors around to face me up front. As soon as I read the question they would click the button and it would change their screens the color red.

The button and background color change is easy enough, I got that. There are two problems I'm facing: 1) I need it so that they can't click the button until I'm done reading the question - this one isn't as important, I can just make up a rule. 2) Only the fastest person will have a red screen. To show me who clicked first. The others' buttons will be disabled.

I just have no idea how to even Google these two things. Like: "Disable button for other users"...? Or maybe, "only one click"...?

Any direction to search is appreciated. Eventually, I'd like to add other aspects to like the presenter could click an "incorrect button" then it would clear the screen and enable all the buttons again, for the answer steal.

Comment: I would suggest looking into websockets, then if it's the first hit, emit the red screen to the user, else ... "too slow"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks really neat but unfortunately I can't alter or start a server. If I'm understanding websockets correctly, I have to open ports. Not in my realm. I was thinking more like JS maybe. I'm okay with that.

Comment: hmm what about Node.js ? it's written in javascript and you could easily add websockets by (for example) adding a package called socket.io

Comment: Wicked! Node.is worked perfectly! I installed it on my projector PC then had my class open a browser to my IP address and the port I used. I made a simple html that has a simple jquery to add their username to a div list, using the space bar as the buzzer. The jquery simply disabled the buzzer right after the keydown. Thank you #goomaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with modern WebSocket or applications interact via TCP. However, WebSocket may be overkill for the simple application with a few teams. I faced the same problem before and developed a simple solution with PHP using Flock to write into a shared file on disk. Only request from one team gets the chance to write into that file. Stick to not to use WebSocket, the web page on client site does some polling to receive the "restart" signal from the server for the new question/round. It can run in LAN, different team gets different site, i.e. http://[server-ip]/team1, http://[server-ip]/team2. 
You can have control over the round: allow them to press button/ restart, start a new question in http://[server-ip]/admin. 
Further improvement can be made in several ways to facilitate your needs (i.e. assign team name, register team, use database instead of a flock file). The code is available here : https://github.com/minhhn2910/buzzergameshow